# Flutter Navigation: What is the best technique to use when navigating to a new screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In order to navigate to a new screen, two of the functionalities flutter provides are the following two approaches:

- **(1)** `Navigator.of(context).push(...)`
- **(2)** `Navigator.push(context, ...)`

After some testing I observed that approach **(1)** rebuilds the widget on which it is called whereas approach **(2)** does not. Is there any drawback I have not discovered in approach **(2)**?

If not, then does it mean that I should use approach **(1)** whenever I want the widget to rebuild after navigating to a new screen, and use approach **(2)** otherwise?

**Edit:**
There is no difference in the two approaches.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/80b526ea62/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart#L1120

Comment: No difference, thank you :)

Comment: sure, your welcome ;-) it seems that your above observations are somehow wrong...

Comment: btw if you see any flutter class or method documentation, like `Navigator.push` for example: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/push.html - you can see the small blue icon on the right side: just click on it...

Comment: I see... that's very helpful thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In navigator.push you can use controllers. but it is somehow difficult e.g in case of text fields of your second page; you have to make controllers for each text field.